# make a selection by attributes of the fourth part of a range of numbers with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am using Arcmap 10.1 and I need to create a script (for use on shapefiles) where I have a input field named "sequence" which is numerical data. I need to select the fourth part of a range of numbers.

For example, 1-100 depending on the amount of data in the shapefile and I need to make a selection by attributes of "sequence" where I divide 100/4 = 25 and the selection is the first  1-25, the second selection of 26-50, the third 50-75, etc.

The number of records can change and be 150/4 = 37 and the selection would be 1-37 the second third etc 38-75[image]

I have the ide of using arcpy.GetCount_management for me to total the records but do not know how to use the resuldato to divide by 4 and then put the result and make the selection with arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management but not how to do this and if this is the right way to do

Comment: the example of the image would be 63 quarters

Comment: This question is pretty unclear.
From what I've deciphered, is you want to create a python script that will get the total amount of records selected, divide this number by four and select each record that is in 1/4 the range of the total records returned?

Comment: yes friend if that's what I need

Comment: yes is correct your comment

Comment: Okay, another followup question, how are the records selected initially?

Comment: numbers log type,

Comment: It might be easier to use model builder - depends if you're selecting by attribute or not.

Comment: whole procedure is perfect I would like to make the selection not "OBJECTID" I would like to make my selection for shp field called "sequence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will take an input shapefile and make selections 1/4 at a time. It utilizes the OBJECTID field to break up your selection, which is useful if you just want it divided sequentially. The code should work even if the number of features aren't evenly divisible by four. Your selections just won't all be the same size.

```py
import arcpy

shp = "path to shapefile"

#Select by attribute must be run on a feature layer.
layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shp, "whatever you want to call it")

#Get the number of records in the layer.
count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(layer).getOutput(0))

#Get name of ObjectID field
oid = [str(x.name) for x in arcpy.ListFields(layer, "*", "OID")][0]

for i in xrange(4):
    #Build SQL statement of the form "OID" >= # AND "OID" < #
    sql = '"{0}" >= {1} AND "{0}" < {2}'.format(oid, i*count/4, (i+1)*count/4)    

    #Run select layer by attributes to return quarters of the data.
    selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, "NEW_SELECTION", sql)    

    #Code here to do what you want with the selection

#Remove layer after you are done.
if arcpy.Exists(layer):
    arcpy.Delete_management(layer)
```

Comment: one more question friend, I understand that right now I is ordered and selecting the data quiriera OID but if I sort by the "sequence of the table that is in the imegen that data change" arcpy.ListFields "and serious consultation call SQL

Comment: @user22547 I'm not sure what you are saying... I'm only using `arcpy.ListFields` to grab the name of the OID field, which can vary based on how your data are stored.